# Hosting ASP.NET Core application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, hosting

Where can I host my ASP.NET CORE application for free.  I tried the Heroku ASP.NET 5 Buildpack, but seems to have issues and ill have to wait for some help before I can host my code to Heroku. Azure is owned by Microsoft and requires a paid subscription. Everything else I found seems to cost money and I don’t have any. Does anybody know where I can host my application for free? I don’t need much space or memory. Thanks!

Comment: Actually Azure Web App Service has a  free option. But you can not use your domain name.  Url will look as your_app_name.azurewebsites.net

Comment: regarding heroku you can try this deploy button https://elements.heroku.com/buttons/oruban/asp.net-core_deploy_on_heroku.

Comment: @Set Oh nice, could you help me move my application over. Its on linux does that matter ?

Comment: @John you can go to linked github repo and use it as template. Repo contains default setup for ASP.NET Core MVC project generated by yo. Debian instance is used for.

Comment: @Set, okay. How do i push my code to it. I'm new to Heroku. Is that even an option ?

Comment: Please see The Free plan - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As sample how to deploy to [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/) you can look on this [deploy button](https://elements.heroku.com/buttons/oruban/asp.net-core_deploy_on_heroku) sample based on custom [build pack](https://github.com/ORuban/aspnetcore-buildpack) for ASP.NET Core. Debian instance is used for deploy.

GitHub repo with deploy sample is located [here](https://github.com/ORuban/asp.net-core_deploy_on_heroku). It contains ASP.NET Core MVC project generated by `yo` and deploymwnt seetup base on `heroku-button` feature (read [here](https://blog.heroku.com/heroku-button) what is it). To quick start you can fork this repo, modify code, update link to your repo in `readme` file (it renders heroku-button) and click on provided deploy button.

! Note, that your forked repo should be public, as required by Heroku (deploy will not work using button in case of private repo).

---

If you already have your github repo, you can add deploy button to it. To do so copy [app.json](https://github.com/ORuban/asp.net-core_deploy_on_heroku/blob/master/app.json) file to your repo and modify parameters in `env` section, then add heroku-button template modifying `readme` file:

```
<a href="https://dashboard.heroku.com/new?template=<link to your repo>">
  <img src="https://www.herokucdn.com/deploy/button.svg" alt="Deploy">
</a>
```

---

You also can use [git](http://deploy%20to%20heroku%20from%20github) directly to deploy on Heroku, but you should manually setup you heroku project using heroku dashboard in this case (deploy button do this automatically). Read more about deployment process [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/deployment).

Comment: Oh okay, so i have to fork it, change the code and then hit the deploy button ? Could i just hit the deploy button and then somehow push my current project repo, or do i have to fork his and then combine my repo with the forked one and then finally hit deploy ?

Comment: yes, you can; I've updated answer

Comment: modify parameters in env section ?

Comment: I get an error There was an issue building your app. This can mean your app.json's project is not a valid Heroku application. Please ensure your app is deployable to Heroku and try again. 
Here is my Repo https://github.com/AndrewKralovec/Forecast-Report

Comment: you should modify Config Variables ("env" section in app.json). PUBLISH_APP_DIR should be "/", as ypur project in root folder, LAUNCH_ASSEMBLY_NAME : "Forecast-Report.dll" (output assembly). Also add "which npm", "which node" in your prepublish script, as heroku may produce error like "no executable found matching command npm/node

Comment: It builds fine, but when i hit view i get "Error.
An error occurred while processing your request."

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122759/discussion-between-set-and-john).